# Spark pivot groupby performance very slow

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, pivot

I am trying to pivot the dataframe of raw data size 6 GB and it used to take 30 minutes time (aggregation function **sum**):

```
x_pivot = raw_df.groupBy("a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f")
                .pivot("g")
                .agg(sum(raw_df("h")
                .cast(DoubleType))
                .alias(""), sum(raw_df("i"))
                .alias("i"))
```

When I changed the aggregate function to **first** it started taking 1.5 hours.
Could you please help me understand why the aggregation function is impacting the performance and how I can improve the performance?

Comment: There's to little details to help. Check partition number and shuffle partition count, also check if data is distributed correctly - maybe it's skewed in your data

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you please let me know how to check for data skewness? What additional information you are looking for?

Comment: Look at jobs details, each task should take similar time to run. Sometimes one task takes a lot more time

Comment: @GeetaSingh did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Shaido I am facing similar issue , any clue how to deal this kind of use-case ?

Answer (score 7):

For the best performance, specify the distinct values of your pivot column (if you know them). Otherwise, a job will be immediately launched to determine them.

like this,
in as **List**

```
x_pivot = raw_df.groupBy("a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f")
    .pivot("g",["V1","V2","V3"])
    .agg(sum(raw_df("h")
    .cast(DoubleType))
    .alias(""), sum(raw_df("i"))
    .alias("i"))
```

V1,V2,V3 are Distinct Values from "g" column.

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: @cph_sto what happened ?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will improve the performance slightly but if I'm correct using a list will give you a O(n^2) time complexity.  For better efficiency store distinct would be column names into  a list and use a for loop to filter and pivot one column at a time AKA (one list element at a time). This should then give you a O(n) time complexity I believe.  I was able to turn a job that takes a few hours into one that runs in 2 minutes now within databricks.

Comment: Can you please show an example code for the same? I'm stuck in the same situation.

Comment: how can you pivot one column at a time? you need all distinct column values to turn multiple rows into one. example pls